# Navigate to the portal home page after any user action(Complete task/Cancel) in the approval workflow.

Tags: 2010

I'm quite new to Sharepoint and have been struggling with the following problem. In the approval workflow where I'm using

collect data from a user, I'm not able to figure out how to have the user redirected back to the portal home page or any other list except of the Tasks list which is set by default (and apparently confuses the user) upon approval or rejection.

The closest thread I found is

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2b74031-cc68-482c-84ea-da330d52a138/navigate-to-page-feature-for-task-form-customized-with-infopath-2010?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

which has another link inside, but unfortunately I'm still not quite there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!